# Find lowest value in a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, return

I want to find and return the minimal value of an id in a string, for example:

```
find_min_id([{"nonid": "-222", "id": 0}, {"id": -101}])
-101
find_min_id([{’id’: 63, 'id': 42}])
42
```

So far I have this:

```
def find_min_id(list):
    return min(list)
```

but that gives:

```
{'id': -101}
```

and I only want the value of the lowest id.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `key` parameter of `min`:

```
def find_min_id(l):
    return min(l, key=lambda d: d.get("id", float('inf')))["id"]
```

This actually finds the min id, and does it without creating a new list.

The only thing is, the elements in your list might not had an `'id'` key. For that reason I had to use `.get("id", float('inf'))`. Thus the function will return `inf` if there is no id key, which might not be desirable. What `min()` does when given an empty list is it throws an exception, so we'd probably like to do the same if none of the dicts we pass it have an `'id'` key. In that case the min of a generator appoach might indeed be better:

```
def find_min_id(l):
    return min(d["id"] for d in l if "id" in d)
```

The other approach would be to check for `inf` as the result of `min`, but this is more cumbersome:

```
import math
def find_min_id(l):
    res = min(l, key=lambda d: d.get("id", float('inf')))["id"]
    if math.isinf(res):
        raise ValueError("No dict has an 'id' key")
    return res
```

Comment: Brilliant. Or is it me that's stupid, didn't think that we only need the `'id'` key..

Comment: This will not work if there is not `id` in it! :P We all used `min` without knowing! :P

Comment: Funny all the answers seek to return `None` if the input is invalid. I say better in that case to get an exception. Depends on what you're doing I guess..

Comment: This is nice for related cases, too, where you want the whole dictionary corresponding to the minimum id and not just the 'id'. You can just remove `['id']` from the end and it still works.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, but works where there is no `id` in the dictionary, and when there is no dictionary with an `id` at all:

```
def find_min_id(lst):
    ids = [d['id'] for d in lst if 'id' in d]
    return min(ids) if ids else None
```

Without exceptions, and without running `min` for artificially extended list (i.e. the answer which puts maximum floats where an entry isn't an id-entry).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> ids = [{"nonid": "-222", "id": 0}, {"id": -101}]
>>> min([val for obj in ids for key, val in obj.items() if key == 'id'])
-101
>>> ids = [{'id': 63}, { 'id': 42}]
>>> min([val for obj in ids for key, val in obj.items() if key == 'id'])
42
```

Try the above.

You can make this into a function definition:

```
def find_lowest(ids):
    return min([val for obj in ids for key, val in obj.items() if key == 'id'])
```

Working [example](http://ideone.com/FeKTah).

Let me explain what I'm doing. Firstly, the `min` function takes in an iterable object as an argument. So, let me demonstrate:

```
>>> min([1,2,3,4,6,1,0])
0
```

So, what this means is this, we are essentially taking the minimum value of the list that we get from this, `[val for obj in ids for key, val in obj.items() if key == 'id']`.

Now, you might be wondering, well whats happening in there? It might be a little intimidating at first, but thats a list comprehension. Whats that you say? Well, in simple terms its a concise we in which we make a list:

Let me start with be first part, and no its not the beginning of the statement:

```
for obj in ids
```

What we are doing here, is iterating over all the dictionary objects in in side of `ids`. Now, we use that object here:

```
key, val in obj.items() if key == 'id'
```

Since object, is a `dict`, we use the `items` function to get a generator that gives a tuple of key, value pairs. In an object like this: `{'id': 100}`, the `id` would be they key and `100` would be the value. So, we are going over *all* the items in the dictionary object, and *if* the `key` happens to be `id`, then we append it to the list:

```
[val
```

Thats what the first part does. The first part of the list comprehension appends *something* to the final list, and that is `val`.

### UPDATE:

If for some reason, the list does not containt *anything* with `id` as a key, then it will throw a `ValueError` as `min` does not accept an empty list, so to remedy this, we can check:

```
def find_lowest(ids):
    _ret = [val for obj in ids for key, val in obj.items() if key == 'id']
    if _ret:
        return min(_ret)
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: Yeah of course that will throw an error. We're all using `min` here! Besides, it isn't mentioned in the question to handle empty lists.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find the 'lowest' dictionaries. What we want is, to find the lowest `'id'` value in the list.

```
def find_min_id(lst):
    return min([d[key] for key in d for d in lst if key=="id"])
```

Also, avoid using `list` as a variable name, it overrides the built-in function `list()`.

A little demo:

```
>>> def find_min_id(lst):
    return min([d[key] for key in d for d in lst if key=="id"])

>>> find_min_id(lst)
-101
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Following code return `None` if no `id` key is in list.

```
>>> data = [{"nonid": "-222", "id": 0}, {"id": -101}, {"nonid":-200}]
>>> min(filter(lambda x: x is not None, map(lambda x: x.get('id', None),
...    data)) or [None])
-101
```

Here `filter(lambda x: x is not None, ...)` filters out dictionaries without id, 
`map(lambda x: x.get('id', None), data)` gets all `id`'s from data, and `or [None]` part treats case when no `id` key will be found in data.

Answer (score 0):

`list` is a built-in type in Python. don't use it as an identifier

```
def find_min_id(my_list)  
    id_list = []
    for record in my_list:
        if 'id' in record:
            id_list.append(record['id'])
    return min(id_list)
```